# Converting a string to UTF 8

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, uint8t

I've currently got a string array and I want to convert this to a UInt8 array? All of the strings are UInt8's, however I can only retrieve it as a string. Any ideas?

```
let stringValues = "[185, 221, 199, 111, 152, 137, 41, 137, 223, 66, 75, 132]"
```

I have each item in the array split up into its individual part, I just don't know how to convert the string to UInt8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var stringValues = "[185, 221, 199, 111, 152, 137, 41, 137, 223, 66, 75, 132]"

stringValues = stringValues.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

var values = [UInt8]()
print(stringValues)
for item in stringValues.componentsSeparatedByString(",") {
    if let value = UInt8(item) {
        values.append(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let stringValues = "[185, 221, 199, 111, 152, 137, 41, 137, 223, 66, 75, 132]"
let uint8Values = stringValues.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:" ,\"[]"))
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty}.flatMap{ UInt8($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

For single `String` conversion to `UInt8`

`let unt = UInt8("231")`

or you can use complete array as array of `UInt8`.

`let stringValues :[UInt8] = [185, 221, 199, 111, 152, 137, 41, 137, 223, 66, 75, 132]`